# How to append lists in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

Hey everyone this code is working fine just one thing to deal with. It overwrites the multiple entries against a key. I need to avoid the overwriting and to save all those entries. Can you help me in this please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import fileinput

#trys to create dictionary from african country list
dic = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    lst = line.split('|')
    links = lst[4].split()
    new=links[0] + ' ' + links[len(links)-1]
    dic[new]=lst[4] # WARNING: overwrites multiple entriess at the moment! :)

for newline in fileinput.input('somefile.txt'):
    asn = newline.split()
    new = asn[0] + ' ' + asn[1]
    if new in dic:
            print "found from " + asn[0] + " to " + asn[1]
            print dic[new]
```

Note: Sys.stdin takes a string in the following format;
1.0.0.0/24|US|158.93.182.221|GB|7018 1221 3359 3412 2543 1873

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since it shadows the builtin function `list()`. Also you're miss ing a colon in the `if` statement, which BTW should probably look like this: `if new in dic:`. At least, that's [the pythonic way](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: What do you expect `dic[dic[new]]` to do, and why? (Hint: what does `dic[new]` do?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a number of problems with your code. The simplest way to do what you describe is to use a `defaultdict`, which gets rid of the explicit `if` and `has_key` (which you should replace by `new in dic` anyway):

```
#trys to create dictionary from african country list
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)   # automatically creates lists to append to in the dict

for line in sys.stdin:
    mylist = line.split('|')    # call it mylist instead of list
    links = mylist[4].split()
    new = links[0] + ' ' + links[-1]   # can just use -1 to reference last item
    dic[new].append(mylist[4])         # append the item to the list in the dict
                                # automatically creates an empty list if needed
```

See eryksun's comment on Gerrat's answer if you're on an old version of Python without `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method called appendlist.  use [append](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
dic[dic[new]].append(list[4])
```

Also, it's inadvisable to use `list` as a variable name.
It is a builtin in python.

Also, this entire section of code:

```
    if ( dic.has_key(new))
        dic[dic[new]].appendlist(list[4])
    else:
       dic[dic[new]] = [list[4]]
```

should instead probably be:

```
    if new in dic:  # this is the preferrable way to test this
        dic[new].append(list[4])
    else:
       dic[new] = [list[4]]
```

Comment: Hi, I have just corrected the mistakes I had made. But still code: dic[dic[new]] = [list[4]] is not working and gives error "'type' subject is not subscriptable".

Comment: @Sohaib - as both @Gerrat and I said in our answers, `dic[dic[new]]` is wrong, however, that shouldn't give a trying to subscript a `type` object (not "subject"!) error. You must have accidentally typed `dict` instead of `dic`, as `dict` is a type object and `dic` is not.

Comment: @Gerrat: I have tried your preferred way to test it and encountered an error "'str' object has no attribute 'append'". I am actually trying to create a dictionary which will contain multiple values against a key, each value is a string. I would then read content of a new file and on comparing keys in dictionary I'll print those values in of key.

Comment: @Sohaib:  it sounds like you've used: `dic[new] = lst[4]`, not `dic[new] = [lst[4]]` as you've posted...is the code above exactly what you're running?

Comment: @Gerrat: yes, as it is in code, I have used it in the same way.

Comment: @Sohaib: What gets passed into the program via sys.stdin?

Comment: @Gerrat:  I am passing strings in this format;    1.0.0.0/24|US|92.93.96.99|GB|7018 1221 7861 3359 1876 2122

Comment: @Sohaib:  There must be some more code you're not showing us.  The only `append` shown in your code shouldn't give that error (unless there's another place you're adding something to `dic`).  Is the line number where you get that error even within the code you've posted??  If not, you should probably start a new question.  When I run the code you've posted with the input you've shown, I don't get that error.

Comment: @Gerrat: I have provided a new code without using dictionary. This is working fine and achieves the desired results. However, I want its implementation with the help of dictionary as this lookup process is very slow on large files I am dealing with. This is what I was trying to achieve in my earlier code which was not working at all with all the suggestions and feed back provided. I think, I was not spot on the main concept in first place so here is to give you all a complete picture.

Comment: @Sohaib:  Your code has changed so much (much cleaner now) as has the thrust of your question.  I think you should roll back all the changes you made to your question above, accept an answer to this question (the community thinks agf's answer is the best, by far), and post what you have above as a new question. (how to speed this code up).

Comment: @Gerrat: Thank you so much for your support. I have posted a new question and hope that I'd find the solution for my problem.

Comment: @Gerrat: This is working just want to save multiple entries by avoiding overwriting.

Comment: @Gerrat: Thanks, I have sorted out the problem with the suggested answer by agf.